# Can I easily reactivate windows aero after changing to Windows 7 basic/classic?

Tags: windows-7, themes, aero

If I manually activate windows 7 basic or Windows classic themes without my RAM running out or an application changing it, can I easily reactivate my aero themes from Appearance an Personalization without going through troubleshooting or "Change window colors and metrics".

I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium, 64-bit

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly: Yes

On the exact same window where you can change your theme to basic or classic, the Personalization screen you where talking about, you will always be able to select whatever theme, including going back to an aero theme, without any problem. Regardless of what theme you are on at the moment of switching.

(Note: it may take a while to switch from an aero theme to a non-aero theme)

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to make sure before I actually changed it.

Comment: If you are just talking about changing theme, yes you can always change it back at the same window where you did the first chance

Comment: How do you enable it?  This single comment does not really answer the authors question, despite, it being accepted.

Comment: Assuming the author knows how to switch theme in the first place and thus knows how to switch it back (its in the question) the only answer is "yes" (which is what I would have posted if there wasn't a min character limit :p, also i was on mobile when I posted that :p)

Comment: You could at least expand your answer to explain how to change it back. Questions and Answers are not just for the benefit of the OP. We have to consider future readers as well.

Comment: added a bit more info, does it look better now?

Comment: @Ramhound I accepted it because it was all I needed to know. Sure, it may be good to add a little more to it for people who don't know how to change themes, but for the question that I was asking, all I needed was a yes or a no.

Comment: Kinda my point, if you don't know how to change theme, you wouldn't have this question